# Flexbox column align items same width but centered without wrapper (css-only)

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive

[image: problem illustration]

This is for a mobile menu, which of course needs to be **responsive**.

The **longest child** should set the width for all the other children

`.index` needs to be full width and height with a background-color.

**CSS only**, please

## I want to solve this issue *without* an extra wrapper.

---

**My code:**

```css
.index {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; /* main-axis vertical */
  justify-content: center; /* main-axis alignment */
  align-items: center; /* neither center nor stretch produce desired result */
}
.index a {
  /* nothing important here */
}
```

```html
<div class="index">
  <a href="">Some item</a>
  <a href="">Some other item</a>
  <a href="">This one long item</a>
  <a href="">Overview</a>
  <a href="">Contact</a>
</div>
```

---

What I tried so far:

- percentaged padding on either the parent (`.index`) or the children (`a`) never got the whole package centered perfectly
- played around with max-width on the items, but ...

## **I want to solve this issue *without* an extra wrapper.**

There are so many things I found out about native flexbox behaviour in the last months that I wonder and wish so much it can handle this use case as well.

Comment: Have you tried using the `padding` property ?

Comment: As I pointed out I tried padding on both the parent `.index` and the children `a` and never got a perfectly centered alignment of the whole box across multiple viewport widths. But I could be wrong.

Comment: Basically, this is not possible with flexbox without a wrapper.

Comment: @Paulie_D, your breaking my heart </3

Answer (score 2):

Why not just remove the flex option:

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.index {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: inline-block;
}
.index > a {
  display: block;
}
.index:after {
  left:50%; 
  top:50%;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: -1;
  background: #525252;
}
```

```html
<div class="index">
  <a href="">Some item</a>
  <a href="">Some other item</a>
  <a href="">This one long item</a>
  <a href="">Overview</a>
  <a href="">Contact</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I need a fullscreen background. Sorry for not-mentioning.

Comment: Hmmm, then I don't think this is possible without an extra wrapper

Comment: Too bad... it could be so easy..
`align-items: match` boom!

Comment: I found a hack using a pseudo-element! check it out

Comment: Why the background-image?

Comment: It could be a colour - just a fullscreen background

Comment: Had a similar solution myself; but viewport-units aren't an option for me here plus the menu is more complicated. For instance: I need scroll on overflow in case (and the case exists) that I have too many items. But looking at what I asked for you kinda have a solution, although I really wanted a less 'hacky' solution. I'll wait a little longer; if nothing better comes up you'll get the answer-points!

Comment: damn, so close!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124631/discussion-between-kater-louis-and-pete).

Answer (score 1):

Try below HTML or CSS code:

```css
.index {
    background-color: #525252;
    position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0;
    width: 100%; height: 100%;

    display: flex; flex-direction: column; // main-axis vertical 
    justify-content: center; // main-axis alignment
    align-items: center; // neither center nor stretch produce desired result

    a {
        ... // nothing important here 
    }
}
.index ul {
  background-color: #5c7343;
  color: #b0c696;
  float: none;
  list-style-type: square;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0 5px 0 15px;
}
.index ul li {
  padding: 3px 0;
}
.index ul li a {
  color: #b0c696;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="index">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Some item</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Some other item</a></li>
    <li><a href="">This one long item</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Overview</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Although your snippet does not what I need it to, it is possible with the `ul`. but this is the wrapper I am trying to avoid.